# Configure phpMyAdmin to connect to another MySql server

Tags: mysql

I have installed WAMP server on my laptop and for the sake of simplicity I want to configure phpMyAdmin to connect to a **mysql server** on another machine so that I can dump the database tables.

If this is possible (and i believe it is), does any1 knows where is phpMyAdmin settings file located?

The location of wamp on my laptop is `C:\wamp`. I've noticed in `C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.5.1` but there are a lot of php scripts in there. Which one of this should I modify?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PHPMyAdmin's [configuration file](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/config.inc.php) is located in the root directory and is called *config.inc.php* and in order to configure the servers to connect to, you can check [this page](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Config/Servers) for more information.

Here's an example how the server configuration should look like:

```
$i++;

/* First server */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'mysql1.example.net';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;

$i++;

/* Second server */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'mysql2.example.net';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
```

Comment: Summarily, possible things you need to check when somehow the phpMyAdmin seems not to connect to the config file at all.

Please refer to my answer in this thread: [why phpMyAdmin cannot connect to RDS server][1]


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74861941/7270736